# Romberg integration with NestList or FoldList?

Tags: syntax

I am using a NestList like this:

```
NestList[((4 #2 - #1)/3) & @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &, T, Length[T] - 1]
```

But the function that is applied on the Partition is not complete, it should include information on the number of the iteration of the NestList.

So the question is: how can I know at what iteration the NestList is? How can I include that information in the function?

BACKGROUND
This is the full program; I am building it for Romberg Integration:

```
n := Range[0, 4]
xA := 1
xB := 2
f[t_] := 1/t
h := (xB - xA)/2^n
xT := xA + h*Range[0, 2^n]
yT := f[xT]
T = h  Map[Total[yT[[#]]] - 1/2 First[yT[[#]]] - 1/2 Last[yT[[#]]] &, 
     Range[1, Length[2^n]]] // N;
nl = NestList[((4 #2 - #1)/3) & @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &, T, 
   Length[T] - 1];
PadLeft[nl] // TableForm
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
n := Range[0, 4]
xA := 1
xB := 2
f[t_] := 1/t
h := (xB - xA)/2^n
xT := xA + h*Range[0, 2^n]
yT := f[xT]
T = h  Map[Total[yT[[#]]] - 1/2 First[yT[[#]]] - 1/2 Last[yT[[#]]] &, 
     Range[1, Length[2^n]]] // N;
nl = FoldList[
   Function[{x, y}, (4^#2 y - x)/(4^#2 - 1)] @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &,
    T, Range[Length[T] - 1]];
PadLeft[nl] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** an alternative approach using [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html):

```
nla = FoldList[Function[{x, y}, ((4 y - x)/3)] @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &, T, 
   Range[Length[T] - 1]];

TeXForm @ Grid[Flatten /@ PadLeft[nla]]
```

> $\begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0.75 & 0.708333 & 0.697024 & 0.694122 & 0.693391 \\
>  0 & 0.694444 & 0.693254 & 0.693155 & 0.693148 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0.692857 & 0.693121 & 0.693145 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0.693209 & 0.693153 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.693135 \\
> \end{array}$

With this approach, you can use the second argument `#2` (the iterator argument) any way you like in the first argument of `FoldList`. For example,

```
nla2 = FoldList[#2 + Function[{x, y}, (4 y - x)/3] @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &, T, 
   Range[Length[T] - 1]];

TeXForm @ Grid[Flatten /@ PadLeft[nla2]]
```

> $\begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0.75 & 0.708333 & 0.697024 & 0.694122 & 0.693391 \\
>  0 & 1.69444 & 1.69325 & 1.69315 & 1.69315 \\
>  0 & 0 & 3.69286 & 3.69312 & 3.69315 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 6.69321 & 6.69315 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10.6931 \\
> \end{array}$

You can also use `NestList` to get the same result as follows:

```
nla3 = Module[{i = 1}, 
   NestList[(i++) + Function[{x, y}, (4 y - x)/3] @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &, T, 
    Length[T] - 1]];

nla2 == nla3
```

> True

**Original answer:**

```
nlb = NestList[{#[[1]] + 1, ((4 #2 - #1)/3)& @@@ Partition[#[[2]], 2, 1]} &, 
   {1, T}, Length[T] - 1];

nlb[[All, 2]] = PadLeft[nlb[[All, 2]]];

TeXForm @ Grid[Flatten /@ nlb]
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccc}
>  1 & 0.75 & 0.708333 & 0.697024 & 0.694122 & 0.693391 \\
>  2 & 0 & 0.694444 & 0.693254 & 0.693155 & 0.693148 \\
>  3 & 0 & 0 & 0.692857 & 0.693121 & 0.693145 \\
>  4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.693209 & 0.693153 \\
>  5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.693135 \\
> \end{array}$

Alternatively, you can post-process `nl` to inject the iteration index using [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
nlc = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, PadLeft @ nl];

TeXForm @ Grid[Flatten /@ nlc]
```

> same picture

Comment: I meant to modify the function ((4 #2 - #1)/3 to make it partly dependent on the iteration, not to show the iteration seperately.

Comment: @GambitSquared, please see the update.

Comment: Great! It works.

Answer (score 2):

If your ultimate goal is implementation of   [Romberg Integration Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method), here is straightforward way to do it using`Table` 
[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[x_] := 1/x
romberg[a_, b_, n_] := Module[{}, h[j_] := (b - a)/2^j;
  R[0, 0] := h[1] (f[a] + f[b]);
  R[j_, 0] := 1/2 R[j - 1, 0] + h[j] \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(j - 1\)]]\(f[a + \((2  i - 1)\) h[j]]\)\);
  R[j_, k_] := (4^k R[j, k - 1] - R[j - 1, k - 1])/(4^k - 1);
  Grid@N[Table[
     If[j == k, Framed@R[j, k], R[j, k]], {j, 0, n}, {k, 0, j}], 15]]
romberg[1, 2, 5]
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccc}
>  \fbox{$0.750000000000000$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  0.708333333333333 & \fbox{$0.694444444444444$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  0.697023809523810 & 0.693253968253968 & \fbox{$0.693174603174603$} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  0.694121850371850 & 0.693154530654531 & 0.693147901481235 & \fbox{$0.693147477644832$} & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  0.693391202207527 & 0.693147652819419 & 0.693147194297078 & 0.693147183071933 & \fbox{$0.693147181916745$} & \text{} \\
>  0.693208208269249 & 0.693147210289823 & 0.693147180787850 & 0.693147180573418 & 0.693147180563620 & \fbox{$0.693147180562297$} \\
> \end{array}$